Azure nginx controller: Unexpected error validating SSL certificate
Im getting the following when access my portal deployed with aks Our services aren't available right now We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon. with nginx controller
Looking at the ingress log I get Unexpected error validating SSL certificate certificate is valid for example-aks-dev.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com, not endpoint endpoint-example-dev-h2a3adekfjkxgrfk.a01.azurefd.net 
Looking in the docs I found Ensure that the certificate order is leaf->intermediate->root, otherwise the controller will not be able to import the certificate, and you'll see this error in the log(previous error), but I don't get how to fix it. I'm not expert and the ingress and other components where created using a helm chart. The tsl section of ingress is commented, meaning (I guess) that the certificate is auto generated and self-signed
when looking at the secrets I get a list:
NAME                                  TYPE                 DATA   AGE
cert-manager-webhook-ca               Opaque               3      304d
dev-example-ingress-nginx-admission   Opaque               3      304d
letsencrypt                           Opaque               1      304d
sh.helm.release.v1.cert-manager.v1    helm.sh/release.v1   1      304d
sh.helm.release.v1.dev-exing.v1     helm.sh/release.v1   1      304d
sh.helm.release.v1.dev-exing.v2     helm.sh/release.v1   1      304d
sh.helm.release.v1.dev-exing.v3     helm.sh/release.v1   1      293d

and when I execute kubectl get pod -n ingress-nginx
I get:
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-67b75f4674-fsqd5                           1/1     Running     0          58d
cert-manager-cainjector-84d4bd898d-d4xhq                1/1     Running     0          58d
cert-manager-webhook-bf4f6d478-mb7gs                    1/1     Running     0          58d
dev-example-ingress-nginx-controller-5f46d75ff-7tsbp    1/1     Running     0          21h
dev-example-ingress-nginx-controller-7cf9494bb7-7jbw4   0/1     Completed   0          58d

I can't find a solution

Seems like there is a mismatch between the SSL certificate being used by the NGINX Ingress controller and the domain you're trying to access. Do a kubectl get secret -n   -o yaml and check  if the certificate is self-signed or not. If it's not valid for your custom domain, you will need to replace it.

@Arko I edited the question to add the output of kubectl get secret -n ingress-nginx. Which one I should check?

The secret associated with your TLS configuration for the Ingress controller is the one responsible for the SSL certificate. You can identify the relevant secret by looking at your Ingress YAML definition under the tls section. Check which secret is being used for TLS in the Ingress file.

It's because the SSL certificate presented by the ingress controller does not match the expected domain, or there is an issue with its chain of trust.
what makes me think so?
The error says the certificate is valid for example-aks-dev.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com but not for the expected domain endpoint-example-dev-h2a3adekfjkxgrfk.a01.azurefd.net. This indicates a mismatch in the certificate's CN or SAN.
How to fix it?
by using a valid SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt, managed through cert-manager.
install cert-manager, which will handle the automation of the SSL certificate issuance from Let's Encrypt.

Make sure your domain points to the external IP of the NGINX Ingress Controller. You can retrieve the IP address using

Update your DNS records to reflect this IP.
Next create a ClusterIssuer to allow cert-manager to issue certificates accordingly

Uncomment the TLS section in your ingress configuration and define your domain and certificate secret. Ingress Resource
something like this-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dev.perfai.us
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-service
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.perfai.us
    secretName: dev-perfai-us-tls



Once the Ingress resource is updated, cert-manager should automatically request a certificate from Let's Encrypt.

As I said, the secret associated with your TLS configuration for the Ingress controller is the one responsible for the SSL certificate. You can identify the relevant secret by looking at your Ingress YAML definition under the tls section. Check which secret is being used for TLS in the Ingress file. Should resolve the issue.
